# Use Google Cloud (Free trial) to render using programs like Premiere Pro and Meshroom

Tags: gpu, virtual-machine, rendering, tpu

Iam trying to use Google Cloud to render video's using Premiere Pro and 3d models using Meshroom, I think I need a VM with a GPU but with the 300$ free trial non-tpu accelerators aren't available. Iam not familiar with TPU's so iam not sure I can use it to render things.